# how to get the number records along with file size in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unit-testing, unix

I am trying to get the file details and the number of records for each file along with size.
i tried with this `ls -lhtr 234*201406*.log.gz` it is giving all the details except record count. if i tried `ls -lhtr 234*201406*.log.gz | wc -l` it is showing the number of files.

present o/p:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins tomcat  120M Jun 30 18:25 234_1404165601_20140630220001.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins tomcat  144M Jun 30 19:24 234_1404169201_20140630230001.log.gz
```

i need o/p as

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins tomcat  120M Jun 30 18:25 234_1404165601_20140630220001.log.gz 20000
```

can you please help me on this to get.thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by number of "records"? Number of lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zcat` (or `gunzip -c`) for printing # of lines from `.gz` files:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; du -h "$f"; zcat "$f" | wc -l' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: 113939938 ./234_1403744401_20140626010001.log.gz
-: gzcat: command not found
0   i am getting like this..

Comment: @Dileep: It's `zcat` or `gunzip -c`. `gzcat` does not indeed exist.

Comment: @JanHudec: I do have `gzcat` as `/usr/bin/gzcat` on my OSX.

Comment: @anubhava: Than OSX apparently has to differ just for sake of it. It's called just `zcat` on all other unices. And this question is explicitly tagged `linux`.

Comment: find . -name '234*201406*.gz' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; stat -c "%s %n" "$f"; zcat "$f" | wc -l' - '{}' \;
 i tried the above command i am getting as 96236882 ./234_1402714801_20140614030001.log.gz
390518. what is the first number(96236882) and last one(390518).

Comment: First number is size of file in bytes and 2nd number is # of lines in the file.

Comment: If the 1st number is size i want to display in MB's.. my output should be like this 120M Jun 30 18:25 234_1404165601_20140630220001.log.gz 20000

Comment: @anubhava : can you please let me know how to print it in MB's.

Comment: ok check updated answer for that. Basically use `du -h` instead of `stat`